# comparing values in two or more keys in python dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to compare the values for 2 or more keys in python dict and return the highest value. I can find max for 2 keys but I am clueless for 3 keys and above.

Here is my code for 2 keys comparison:

```
d = {}
d['right'] = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5]
d['left'] = [0.2, 0.1, 0.4]
result = [list(d)[0] if x > y else list(d)[1] for x,y in zip(list(d.values())[0], list(d.values())[1])]
# result: ['left', 'right', 'right']
```

now what's the best way to do it for 3 keys?

```
# input:
d = {}
d['right'] = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5]
d['left'] = [0.2, 0.1, 0.4]
d['back'] = [0.0, 0.2, 0.8]
# expected result: ['left', 'right', 'back']
```

PS: *I try not to use `numpy`, `pandas`, or any library possible. Or if I have to use, I try to stick with whatever base library available in python.*

Comment: dict is not a good data structure for this task.  consider using dataframes instead.

Comment: umm yea...I try not to use `numpy`, `pandas`, `Collections` or any library. Or maybe the least library possible. Sorry I forgot to include that in my question.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with `collections`. It is a standard Python library, unlike `pandas` , etc.

Comment: Trying not to use libraries is misguided. One of Python's greatest strengths is the ease of importing and using libraries, so you can pick the best tool for the job.

Comment: I am wondering why am I being downvoted? Choosing to use library or not is my own choice. I am simply saying I want to use as minimum library as possible. I am trying to emulate a machine learning algorithm to understand the algorithm flow better. Not sure how I am wrong in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should sort the dictionary key/value pairs by values in the descending order:

```
keys,_ = zip(*sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True))
keys
#('left', 'right', 'back')
```

You can use `itemgetter` instead of the `lambda`, if you prefer:

```
from operator import itemgetter
keys,_ = zip(*sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
```

Comment: What if I have more values in my dict keys? I want it to return something like `['left', 'right', 'back', 'back', 'left']` for example. They `keys` returned there is a set, can only return the unique values.

Comment: The variable `keys` has all keys from your dictionary, use as many as you like. The keys are returned as a tuple, not as a set. Also, all dictionary keys are unique by definition.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
l1 = zip(*d.values())
l2 = list(d.keys())

[l2[i.index(max(i))] for i in l1]
```

Output:

```
['left', 'right', 'back']
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct N dict for N values, and compute each one:

```
d = {}                                                                              
d['right'] = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5]                                                        
d['left'] = [0.2, 0.1, 0.4]                                                         

dct = [dict(zip(d.keys(), [v[i] for v in d.values()])) for i in range(len(d.values()[0]))]
keys = [sorted(d.keys(), key=lambda key:d[key], reverse=True)[0] for d in dct]
# ['left', 'right', 'right']
```